# Magento 2.4 : How to override \Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorderp model?

Tags: overrides, magento2.4, render

```
Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput must be compatible with Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder::execute(string $orderNumber, string $storeId): Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput
```

I am getting the above error while trying to override the module. I am trying with the preference to override the execute method.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder" type="Test\CustomReorder\Model\Reorder\Reorder"/>
</config>
```

file:

```
 <?php

namespace Test\CustomReorder\Model;

class Reorder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder
{
 public function execute(string $orderNumber, string $storeId): Data\ReorderOutput
    { 
       $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('confirmed');
die('abc');      
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of preference try to use Before or After plugins.
Full instruction: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

Just find which method you need override and create after/before (don't use around) plugin for them.

Comment: On my side I'm always using preferences, it's always the better and quickest way to know that all the file is extended. I think plugin would be more if you just want to modify an output for example. I would say it just depends on what he wants to do with his data.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing to call the parent constructor.

So your Reorder class needs to have a `__construct` method in wich one you will at least have the following `:__construct(...)`

Where `...` will be the list of the parent constructor. If you are using an ide like PhpStorm he should fill all the paremeters for you using the extends.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below override class i.e. `Test\CustomReorder\Model\Reorder\Render.php`. It would only works for valid for Magento 2.4.x only.

Also, double confirm the `type="Test\CustomReorder\Model\Reorder\Reorder` in the `di.xml` as well and check namespace in PHP class.

```
<?php
namespace Test\CustomReorder\Model\Reorder;


use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CustomerCartResolver;
use Magento\Quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCartResolver;
use Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder as ReorderHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;

class Reorder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder
{

    public function __construct(OrderFactory $orderFactory, CustomerCartResolver $customerCartProvider, GuestCartResolver $guestCartResolver, CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository, ReorderHelper $reorderHelper, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($orderFactory, $customerCartProvider, $guestCartResolver, $cartRepository, $reorderHelper, $logger, $productCollectionFactory);
    }

    public function execute(string $orderNumber, string $storeId): Data\ReorderOutput
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('confirmed');
        die('abc');
    }
}
```